# javascript ignore string and decimal point number in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

please i have an array [ 45, 66, 90, 'bye', 100.5 ] 
and I want to write a javascript function to ignore the 'bye' and also the ".5" and get a return array of [ 45, 66, 90, 100 ] as my output but I don't know how to go about it I'm new to javascript. this is what I tried

```js
var filterFloat = function(value) {
  if (/^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|Infinity)$/.test(value))
    return Number(value);
  return NaN;
}

console.log(filterFloat('100.5'))
```

Comment: https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%28%5C-%7C%5C%2B%29%3F%28%5B0-9%5D%2B%28%5C.%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%3F%7CInfinity%29%24%2F

Comment: Your regex allows decimal points

Comment: thanks bro nice code but how to i implement it to this code:

function which takes in an array integers, and should return an array of the inputed integers sorted such that the odd numbers come first and even numbers come last.

function mySort(nums) {
  var ar = [];
  var br =[];
  var cr;
for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if(nums[i] % 2 !=1) { // index is even
        ar.push(nums[i]);
        cr = ar;
        cr.sort(function(a, b){return a-b})

    }
  else{
    br.push(nums[i]);
  }
}
return (br.concat(cr));
}mySort([90, 45, 66])

Comment: @innocentigwonobe I would make that another question as it's not the best to post code in comments or change the scope of the question as you are asking 2 different things. But as for your function in you comment I would sort `nums` before going into your loop. Push odds to one, evens to another, then concat and you will be sorted already.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce`. You can use `Math.floor` to round down the number.

```js
var arr = [ 45, 66, 90, 'bye', 100.5 ];
 
var result = arr.reduce((c,v)=>{
    if ( !isNaN( v ) ) c.push( Math.floor( v ) );
    return c;
},[]);
 
console.log( result );
```

Doc: [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:

- Parse the value in array to convert it into `integer`. This will convert the values to `integer`
- Then you can check whether the parsed value is actually a number or not using `isNaN` method. This will help you to detect the `string` values in the array which you can omit in your result set.

```js
 var arr = [ 45, 66, 90, 'bye', 100.5 ];
 var result = [];
 arr.map((item) => {
   if(!isNaN(parseInt(item))){
     result.push(parseInt(item));
   }
 });
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter answer:

```
var result = t.map(i => parseInt(i)).filter(Boolean)
```

Comment: This does filter out `0` (although admittedly, that isn't in the example data)